# Best practice using myown.cls or include file with dependancies

Tags: document-classes

I made my self a myclass.cls file that contains all dependancies i commonly use. That file declares the Paperformat and is laying side by side with my main.tex file. Now after some time and several documents i wrote i have several different such files... So im thinking of outsourcing that file to the user/MYUSER/Library/texmf/tex/latex folder
but how can i controll the Paperformat in each document by it self?

main.tex:

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdfLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
%!BIB program = Bibtex

% Dokument definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{myclass}
```

myclass.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ih-document}
\LoadClass[
10pt,
a4paper
]{article}
```

is it possible to hand over a value to the class somehow?

Something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{myclass}
```

Comment: `\PassOptionsToClass`, but your question is unclear, in my point of view

Comment: what is unclear?

Comment: Read source2e.pdf (from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en) starting on page 361.

Comment: uh. that doc has 520 pages and i hardly understand the first...
Im only asking for samples how other people work...

Comment: Use package geometry to declare the page format.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the [clsguide](http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
% \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} not really required nowadays -- doesn't hurt, though
\ProvidesClass{myclass}% the name should match the filename!

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname f@size\endcsname}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

#### Remark

Before you run this example file please be aware that

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
...
\end{filecontents*}
```

*overwrites* any existing `myclass.cls` without warning!

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer not to load `filecontents`?

Comment: @cfr probably. But OTOH I don't believe that the real class is really named “myclass” so the risk isn't too high :)

Comment: You would be surprised. 'Oh, this is where I put my class name - great! Now, then, ...'

Comment: No I wouldn't, hence my warning. :)  but the OP has  `\ProvidesClass{ih-document}` so...